# Exclude form button from 'onblur' event, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick, onblur

I have a form that uses `onblur` for most of the input fields, like follows:

```
<form>
<input name="..." id="..." onblur="myFunction(name)" />
<button id="..." onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The form validates certain fields (i.e. username, email) in real time via the `onblur` events, but the same check happens when the user clicks the submit button.

Currently, when the user clicks the submit button, the `onblur` event is first triggered, and then the `onclick` event from the button is triggered - thus running the check twice and wasting a couple extra seconds.

Is there any way to override the `onblur` method to exclude the blur that happens when the user presses the submit button?

I was thinking a simple `if(/*button is clicked*/){}` within `myFunction()`, but I wouldn't know how to check for the button click. And it seems, based on the current performance, that the button click is not even registered until after the blur.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"wasting a couple extra seconds"* - What are you doing in `myFunction()` that is measured in *seconds*?

Comment: Ajax call do database to check username availability. Maybe not quite a couple seconds, but enough time that it bothers me. As the validation occurs, a pinwheel appears. The same pinwheel appears upon the submit button being pressed. So the user sees: pinwheel -> confirmation of input (very briefly) -> pinwheel -> repeat confirmation of input. It just looks ugly and glitchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

HTML

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="id" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input:not([type="submit"])', function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode;  // the key pressed
   var elem = e.target;  // the element blurred 
   myFunction(name);
});

$(document).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function() {
   submit();
});
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the problem. The original code doesn't have a blur handler on the submit button. The question is how to prevent the blur handlers on *other* inputs running if they had the focus before a click on the submit button.

Comment: This might work, but maybe a silly question: in the first method, how do I get a) the event (specifically the keycode) to cause the blur, as well as the name of the field in which the blur occurred?

Comment: Yup, that'll do it! Thanks! You're missing a square bracket in the onclick portion, otherwise great. I needed specifically `e.target.id`, but otherwise spot on!